# Are all the instructions in WebAssembly encoded with “uint8” numbers?

Tags: webassembly

[image]

Are all the instructions in WebAssembly encoded with “uint8” numbers like shows above? The WebAssembly standard just says like below:

> In the MVP, the opcodes of instructions are all encoded in a single byte since there are fewer than 256 opcodes.

which I need to confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed that you have been asking a lot of questions reqarding the WebAssembly spec. These might be better asked on the spec repo: https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec - also, please remember to accept good answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification states that for WebAssembly modules encoded in binary format:

> Instructions are encoded by opcodes. Each opcode is represented by a single byte, and is followed by the instruction’s immediate arguments, where present.

It then proceeds to detail the opcode for each instruction, for example:

```
instr::=
     0x1A ⇒ drop 
     0x1B ⇒ select
```

The specification gives you the specific values for the bytes, therefore a signed, or unsigned interpretation is meaningless.

Comment: That'll be inaccurate past MVP. Future opcodes don't fit in a byte and instead use a prefix byte. See SIMD as an example: https://github.com/WebAssembly/simd/blob/master/proposals/simd/BinarySIMD.md

This was decided at the following meeting (search for "prefix"): https://github.com/WebAssembly/meetings/blob/master/2017/CG-05.md